# pyPdf PdfFileReader vs PdfFileWriter

Tags: python, pypdf

I have the following code:

```
import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = "C:/Real Python/Course materials/Chapter 12/Practice files"

input_file_name = os.path.join(path, "Pride and Prejudice.pdf")
input_file = PdfFileReader(file(input_file_name, "rb"))
output_PDF = PdfFileWriter()

for page_num in range(1, 4):
    output_PDF.addPage(input_file.getPage(page_num))

output_file_name = os.path.join(path, "Output/portion.pdf")
output_file = file(output_file_name, "wb")
output_PDF.write(output_file)
output_file.close()
```

Till now I was just reading from Pdfs and later learned to write from Pdf to txt... But now this...
Why the `PdfFileReader` differs so much from `PdfFileWriter`

Can someone explain this? I would expect something like:

```
import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = "C:/Real Python/Course materials/Chapter 12/Practice files"

input_file_name = os.path.join(path, "Pride and Prejudice.pdf")
input_file = PdfFileReader(file(input_file_name, "rb"))

output_file_name = os.path.join(path, "out Pride and Prejudice.pdf")
output_file = PdfFileWriter(file(output_file_name, "wb"))

for page_num in range(1,4):
    page = input_file.petPage(page_num)
    output_file.addPage(page_num)
    output_file.write(page)
```

Any help???
Thanks

**EDIT 0:** What does .addPage() do?

```
for page_num in range(1, 4):
        output_PDF.addPage(input_file.getPage(page_num))
```

Does it just creates 3 BLANK pages?

**EDIT 1:** Someone can explain what happends when:

1) `output_PDF = PdfFileWriter()`

2) `output_PDF.addPage(input_file.getPage(page_num))`

3) `output_PDF.write(output_file)`

The 3rd one passes a JUST CREATED(!) object to `output_PDF` , why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is basically the PDF Cross-Reference table.

It's a somewhat tangled spaghetti monster of references to pages, fonts, objects, elements, and these all need to link together to allow for random access.

Each time a file is updated, it needs to rebuild this table. The file is created in memory first so this only has to happen once, and further decreasing the chances of torching your file.

```
output_PDF = PdfFileWriter()
```

This creates the space in memory for the PDF to go into. (to be pulled from your old pdf)

```
output_PDF.addPage(input_file.getPage(page_num))
```

add the page from your input pdf, to the PDF file created in memory (the page you want.)

```
output_PDF.write(output_file)
```

Finally, this writes the object stored in memory to a file, building the header, cross-reference table, and linking everything together all hunky dunky.

Edit: Presumably, the JUST CREATED flag signals PyPDF to start building the appropriate tables and link things together.

--

in response to the why vs .txt and csv:

When you're copying from a text or CSV file, there's no existing data structures to comprehend and move to make sure things like formatting, image placement, and form data (input sections, etc) are preserved and created properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am just wondering why this has to be that way? Why not when copying from a .txt file or an .csv file???

Comment: When you're copying from a text or CSV file, there's no existing data structures to comprehend and move to make sure things like formatting, image placement, and form data (input sections, etc) are preserved and created properly.

Comment: thanks very much again! Please add the info from your comment to your answer! I "lol reward you with the 50 bounty in about 5 hours since it won't let me right now!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's done because PDFs aren't exactly linear - the "header" is actually at the end of the file.

If the file was written to disk every time a change was made, your computer needs to keep pushing that data around on the disk. Instead, the module (probably) stores the information about the document in an object (PdfFileWriter), and then converts that data into your actual PDF file when you request it.

Comment: Please check my Edit.. One more question!

Comment: When you create your `PdfFileWriter`, you're basically creating a blank PDF. With `addPage`, you're appending pages 1, 2 and 3 (in that order) from the original document to the new one. i.e. you're making a new document with only the first 3 pages of the other document.

Comment: I really can't understnad this syntax at all...
If whith PdfFileWriter() , I create a Pdf and with the     addPage() , I write text, then what do I need the last 4 line of code? :S